# URL Rewriting and htaccess files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hoping someone can help.  I use nibbler to check out my website to make sure it behaves well and one of the categories is URL FORMAT which

> Avoid use of file extensions wherever possible.... Consider URL rewriting as an effective
>   and transparent means of creating appropriate URLs.

Anyway, I use Dreamweaver to create and edit the site and if I convert it to using index.htm  files in directories (which would solve this) then this just seems to make life complicated.

Is there some *MAGIC* that I can do in the .htaccess file that means i can still upload it as .htm's and it does some cool stuff in the background and shows them better.

for example I would like

http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog.htm

to become

http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.htm[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.htm [L]
```

Comment: What does it actually do?

Also will it automatically default to the version WITHOUT the extension (which would be the desired effect)

Comment: This provides **extension less** access to your files.

Comment: Also I would like it to automatically default to the version WITHOUT the extension (the desired effect)

Comment: Hmmm...  :) - It's a little scarey as I have no clue what it's doing but it's working for the most part.  Can be be adjusted to take into account the main index.htm as it's currently showing 

www.website.org/index

not just

www.website.org

Comment: Still has same effect ?

Here's my testing site - http://psychologybasket.com/index.htm

Comment: For me i stayed at `http://psychologybasket.com/index.htm` is that not what you wanted?

Comment: no - for the root I want it to be
(http://psychologybasket.com/) not (http://psychologybasket.com/index.htm)

Comment: By the way - I do appreciate your help :)

Comment: Wow - Thanks, you're a star!  I still don't fully understand what it's doing but it seems to do it nicely

Comment: One more thing... if they put http://psychologybasket.com/Nicks-About-Us/ is there an easy way to make it the same as without the trailing slash?  -- As I get a 404 message if a / is added to the end

Comment: You're a Star! - Thanks

Comment: OK, I have found a problem due to using the above code, it's not a huge problem (I don't think so anyway), i know a way round it, but its a bit inconvenient.  When I try to create a sitemap using any of the online versions, it misses MANY of the pages, try creating a site map for [link](http://www.Beingchildren.org) for example, it actually has around 69 html pages, although now using sitemap generators it only creates about 40-50 links and it gives an error saying too many retries for the ones it doesn't add.  Any Solutions or do I have to put up with it??? - THANKS

Comment: Can you tell me examples of some site URLs that result into redirect loop. I can investigate the rules based on that.

Comment: If you use this sitemap generator, it kindly tells you which ones...

http://www.sitemapdoc.com/

so just check one of my sites below..

http://www.beingchildren.org
or
http://www.primatetrustindia.org

Comment: I am not convinced about their report. For example it said too man redirects with `http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Pictures.htm` and then  opened same URL with my browser and from command line curl it came back fine with just a single redirect to remove `.htm`.

Comment: Have the same problem with all the on-line sitemap generators, but like you said there is no problem getting to the pages normally.  I tested that and all pages were accessible, it's just the on-line sitemap generators which get stuck.

Comment: Most likely they are using some old cached data since browsers or curl are not reporting any problem.

Comment: Another little query as my redirects aren't working and I don't know why.  I have added your code at the top and below it I have 301 redirects.  

Redirect 301 /Blog/2012-12-25-Christmas-Presents.htm http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog

For example : does the url to redirect need it's .htm extension (as your code removes it), and the url i am directing to, does that want its .htm extension or not??? 

What ever I seem to do does not have the desired effect

Comment: I think I replied in detail on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542017/301-redirects-not-working-anyone-know-why

Comment: There are a couple of urls that are not working, it's saying too many re-directs in google webmaster tools - 

http://www.beingchildren.org/Blog/2013-03-12-Health-Packs-Clothes.htm

Comment: I sorted it thanks, (I think) it was because there was a directory as the same name as the htm file (once the htm was removed)