# 301 Redirects not working - Anyone know why?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Can someone help?  For some reason the 301 redirects are not working....   The rewrite conditons format my urls by removing the extensions, so not sure if I need to remove the extensions from the 301 statements or not.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.beingchildren\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.beingchildren.org/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.htm[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.htm [L]


errordocument 404 /404.php

Redirect 301 /Blog/2012-12-25-Christmas-Presents.htm http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog
Redirect 301 /Blog/2013-03-29-Mixed-Slum-Photos.htm http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog
Redirect 301 /Blog/2013-05-14-Monthly-Slum-Visits-1.htm http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog
Redirect 301 /Blog/2013-06-12-Panjim-Monsoon.htm http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog
Redirect 301 /Blog/2013-06-15-Margao-Charity-Donations-1.htm http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog
Redirect 301 /Blog/2013-09-08-Margao-Ganesh-Celebrations.htm http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog
Redirect 301 /Blog/2013-09-08-Margao-Ganesh-Holidays.htm http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog
Redirect 301 /Charity.htm http://www.beingchildren.org
Redirect 301 /Children-Charity-Pictures.htm http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of 2 issues:

- 301 rules are at the bottom after `.htm` is removed
- mixing of `mod_alias` and `mod_rewrite` rules

Try this code instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.beingchildren\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.beingchildren.org/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^Blog/2012-12-25-Christmas-Presents\.htm$ http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^Blog/2013-03-29-Mixed-Slum-Photos\.htm$ http://www.beingchildren.org/Children-Charity-Blog [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.htm[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.htm [L]
```

**PS:** I have converted only top 2 of your 301 rules. Once those are working you can similarly convert rest.

Comment: so, if I do the rest as RewriteRule - with the 301 in the square brackets, I would no longer require the seperate Redirect 301 conditions??

Comment: Yes correct you won't need those `Redirect 301` lines.